# Grouping classes

Tags: c#

I have 3 classes called SmallStick, LongStick and OldShovel.
Now I want a list of these classes in one class.

These are my classes:

```
public class SmallStick : IItem
{
    public string ItemName = "Small Stick";
    public ItemType ItemType = ItemType.WEAPON;
}

public class LongStick : IItem
{
    public string ItemName = "Long Stick";
    public ItemType ItemType = ItemType.WEAPON;
}

public class OldShovel : IItem
{
    public string ItemName = "Old Shovel";
    public ItemType ItemType = ItemType.TOOL;
}
```

Now I want a class like this:

```
public class Inventory
{
  List</*Class that represents every kind of these Items above*/> Items = new 
  List<...>();
}
```

Comment: We are still missing `IItem`.

Comment: I think you need to reconsider your comment

Comment: And I think you should improve your question.

Comment: I does not matter what `IItem` is. By the way, you can conclude the content of `IItem` by taking a look at the implementing classes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a list of type `IItem`.

```
List<IItem> Items = new List<IItem>();

...

Items.Add(new SmallStick());
Items.Add(new LongStick());
Items.Add(new OldShovel());
```

---

Assuming an interface declaration (in interfaces you can declare properties, but you cannot declare fields. In fact you can only declare methods, where  properties are just a pair of getter and setter methods).

```
public interface IItem
{
    string ItemName { get; }
    ItemType ItemType { get; }
}
```

You can access these properties for all the item types implementing the interface

```
foreach (IItem item in Items) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.ItemName} is a {item.ItemType}");
}
```

However, since these are properties, the classes would have to be declared like this (C# 6.0 syntax):

```
public class SmallStick : IItem
{
    public string ItemName => "Small Stick";
    public ItemType ItemType => ItemType.WEAPON;
}
```

which is a short syntax for

```
public class SmallStick : IItem
{
    public string ItemName { get { return "Small Stick"; } }
    public ItemType ItemType { get { return ItemType.WEAPON; } }
}
```